# If $f$ and $g$ are independent polynomials and $h$ is a nonzero polynomial, then $fh$ and $gh$ are independent

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am doing some problems outside of class and have a couple of questions that I cannot figure out how to start.

1. If $f$ and $g$ are independent polynomials and $h$ is a nonzero polynomial over $F$, show that $fh$ and $gh$ are independent.

I think this is relatively intuitive, but cannot find a proof for it.

Since f and g are independent, that means they should each form a basis for the fields they are over (in terms of polynomials). Consequently, I believe multiplying by a nonzero polynomial is the equivalent of scaling it in the field. So, the only way they would be dependent is if $h=0$ or if $f=g=0$.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I messed up and forgot to edit the title

Comment: Also, a question should contain a single question, not two.

Comment: I am a bit curious. Why did you select the tags *finite-fields* and *irreducible-polynomials*? I suspect that they came from the surrounding context from the material you are studying. It is just that neither seems really a great fit to this precise question.

Comment: As Matt Samuel pointed out, it is not clear what kind of independence are we talking about. Linear? Algebraic? My answer assumed the first, but if the polynomials have several variable the second is also a possibility. Please give a bit more information about the context where you saw this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question reveals a few points where your understanding may be shaky. Leading off by pointing them out:

1. For the question to make sense it seems likely to me that we are to discuss *linear* independence of these polynomials *over the field of coefficients* $F$.
2. For that to make sense those polynomials must be viewed as elements of some vector space $V$ over $F$. The natural candidate for $V$ is the ring of polynomials $V=F[x]$. But then $V$ is an infinite-dimensional space, so it is impossible for either $f$ or $g$ to form a basis for $V$. We cannot view them as elements of $F$.
3. Linear independence of two polynomials, $p_1$ and $p_2$, in $F[x]$ means that it should be impossible to find constants $c_1,c_2\in F$, not both equal to zero, such that $c_1p_1+c_2p_2=0$. Equivalently (this holds for any two vectors in any vector space) the polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$ are linearly dependent if and only if one is a scalar multiple of the other. So for example polynomials $p_1(x)=1+x+x^2$ and $p_2(x)=2+2x+2x^2$ are linearly dependent because $2p_1+(-1)p_2=0$ or because $p_2=2p_1$. OTOH the polynomials $p_1(x)=x$ and $p_2(x)=x^2$ are linearly independent because they are of a different degree.

On with the actual exercise. Only a hint here - at least for now. Clearing up items 1-3 is IMO more important. More concepts of abstract algebra are coming up.

We are given that $f,g\in F[x]$ are linearly independent over $f$ and that $h\in F[x]$ is a non-zero polynomial. Linear independence of polynomials $fh$ and $gh$ is asking whether there might be scalars $c_1,c_2\in F$ such that
$$
c_1 fh+c_2 gh=0\qquad(1)
$$
in the ring $F[x]$. Because $F[x]$ is a ring we can use the distributive law to rewrite $(1)$ in the form
$$
(c_1 f+c_2 g)h=0.\qquad(2)
$$
Now you need to call upon a special property of $F[x]$ to deduce from this another equation where $h$ no longer appears. I feel that this is the point of this exercise, so I won't take a swing at it (but I did put the ball on the tee for you). You should arrive at an equation that allows you to deduce that we must have $c_1=c_2=0$ for $(1)$ to hold.

Comment: And here I was interpreting it as algebraic independence of multivariate polynomials...

Comment: @MattSamuel: Hmm. That's certainly a live possibility! May be I was mislead by the *linear-algebra* tag. Waiting for the OP to comment before I delete :-)

Comment: As a quick finish to your proof above, depending on which definitions and such are known at this point, we recall that if $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is, generally, an integral domain. This now implies that $F[x]$ contains no divisors of zero. This allows us to disregard $h$, since $h$ is a nonzero polynomial. By the linear $independence$ of $f,g$ in $F[x]$, we must have $c_{1}=c_{2}=0_{F}\in F$ and we are done.  Good discussion...this problem is in Haufmann's/Kunze's, "Linear Algebra," $2$nd Edition -- which is a GREAT book is may say so myself.